# how does property maven.compiler.target work

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

As we know, in maven project, we can set the following properties to specify the java version for plugin maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```

The problem is, should we install jdk8 locally if we want to use the above properties?

Comment: If you want to compile for JDK 8 you should JDK8 at minimum...if you are using JDK9+ you should use also `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` as well which means also all other properties to be changed to `8` instead of `1.8`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile with JDK8 or higher. So if you do not use a different JDK for your compilation, you should run Maven with JDK8 or higher.